# SELECT from a distinct list

Tags: mysql

I'm running the folowing query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hardware_id, model, make from Table1 order by hardware_id;
```

My problem is that in the set of result, I want to see the results where only if hardware_id appears more than once.

Example:

hardware 1  model1 make 1

hardware 1  model2 make 1

hardware 2  model2 make 1 > *I don't want to see this because there's only 1 occurence of hardware 2*

hardware 3  model2 make 1

hardware 3  model2 make 1

Any idea how I can do this?

=====

The prob is that I can't use the following query because of my DISTINCT Flag:

`SELECT hardware_id,model,make from Table1 WHERE hardware_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT hardware_id, model, make from Table1 order by hardware_id) where count(hardware_id) >= 2;`

I need absolutely to use distinct (hardware_id, model, make)

Any idea?

Comment: Does the table have a PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Are there rows with exactly the same `hardware_id`, `model` and `make` ?

Comment: no, the triplet (hardware_id, model, make) has to be distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT hardware_id, model, make 
FROM table1
GROUP BY hardware_id  --  group by orders the rows ASC as a side effect.
HAVING count(hardware_id) > 1
```

However this will select * random * values for `model` and `make`.
You might want to consider using:

```
SELECT hardware_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(model,' - ',make)) AS modelmakes 
FROM table1
GROUP BY hardware_id  --  group by orders the rows ASC as a side effect.
HAVING count(hardware_id) > 1
```

You can also do a join against the first select to get all rows you need, you should not need distinct.

```
SELECT t1.hardware_id, t1.make, t1.make 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT hardware_id 
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY hardware_id  
    HAVING count(hardware_id) > 1
           ) t2 ON (t1.hardware_id = t2.hardware_id)
```

Comment: You'll need `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(model, ,'-', make))` to distinguish table with rows `hard1, model1, make1` and `hard1, model2, make2` from table with rows `hard1, model1, make2` and `hard1, model2, make1`

Comment: I get this set of result :
Mac@ E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,K3715,K3715,E1752,E1752,E1752,K3715,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752,E1752 huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei,huawei ---
How do I eliminate the duplicates?

Comment: Ok, ypercube's comment made it look like:

Mac@|K3765-huawei,K3765-huawei,K3765-huawei,K3765-huawei,E1612-huawei,K3765-huawei 

Still need to eliminate the duplicates from ROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(model,'-',make))

Comment: @Rgonomike, I thought within a `productid` the combo make+model would be unique. Anyway the updated code should fix your issues.

Comment: Excellent, that's the solution. GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(model,'-',make)).

Comment: @Rgonomike, the real problem is of course that your database is not normalized.

Comment: @Johan: You are right, he either has other columns or the table is not normalized.

Comment: As a complement to this comment, I would like to see a result only if there is more than 1 Make/Model concat. Is that possible?
Yes, the DB is not normalised but it's my company's choice.

Comment: @ypercube: How can I eliminate the rows where I only have 1 make/model combo?

Comment: @Rgonomike, Change the having line to `having (count(hardware_id) > 0 and count(concat(make,model)) > 0`

Comment: Arf... Obvisously! 

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I don't think that works. I'd use: `HAVING count(DISTINCT model, make) > 1`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT hardware_id, model, make 
FROM Table1 AS t
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM Table1 AS td
        WHERE td.hardware_id = t.hardware_id
          AND td.id <> t.id                 --- if id is the PK of the table
      )
ORDER BY hardware_id
```

---

Since the table has duplicate `(hardware_id, model, make)` triplets, you can use this instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hardware_id, model, make 
FROM Table1 AS t
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM Table1 AS td
        WHERE td.hardware_id = t.hardware_id
          AND (td.model, td.make) 
              <> (t.model, t.make)               
      )
ORDER BY hardware_id
```

Comment: why not a simple `group by ... having`?

Comment: @Johan: `GROUP BY .. HAVING` and `JOIN`, you mean.

Comment: Hi, the primary key is called "id". The trick is that the triplet (hardware_id, model, make) has to be distinct!

Comment: No, group by having, see my answer below. Am I mistaken, or did I miss something?

Comment: @Rgonomike: Are there rows with exactly the same hardware_id, model and make ?

Comment: no, the triplet (hardware_id, model, make) has to be distinct.

Comment: @Rgonomike: I ask again. Are there in the table any 2 rows with identical hardware, identical model and identical make?

Comment: If these triplets are already distinct in the table, the above query will work.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed. It seems like GROUP_CONCAT is a good solution as it gives me all the models and makes per hardware_id. The only prob is, how do I eliminate the duplicates in models and make?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to sub-query the hardware ids which are repeated, and join this list to your query. The sub-query could be:

```
SELECT hardware_id
FROM Table1
GROUP BY hardware_id
HAVING COUNT(hardware_id) > 1
```

Then, you can join it to your original query:

```
SELECT hardware_id, model, make 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t1.hardware_id
    FROM Table1 t1
    GROUP BY t1.hardware_id
    HAVING COUNT(t1.hardware_id) > 1
) AS join1 ON (join1.hardware_id = Table1.hardware_id)
ORDER BY hardware_id ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT hardware_id, model, make from Table1 where hardware_id in 
    (select hardware_id 
     from TABLE1 group by hardware_id having count(hardware_id) > 1);
```

Another version:

```
SELECT hardware_id, model, make from Table1 t where EXISTS( 
    select hardware_id 
     from TABLE1 where hardware_id = t.hardware_id 
     group by hardware_id having count(hardware_id) > 1
);
```